# PHP regex: remove everything between the last occurrence of <br> and a string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

In a text, I want to remove everything between the last occurrence of `<br>` and a string.

Let's say I have this text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br> 
consectetur adipisicing elit, <br> 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br> 
Some text I want to remove because it is useless.
```

I want to remove everything between the last `<br>` and "useless." (including the delimiters).

The expected result would be:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br> 
consectetur adipisicing elit, <br> 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

Comment: Show us what you tried, and we maybe can fix it.

Comment: It wasn't an answer at all. This is not a site where we write code for you, but help you with your code. And you didn't show any...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = <<< EOD
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consectetur adipisicing elit, <br>
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br>
Some text I want to remove because it is useless.
EOD;

echo(preg_replace('/(?s)<br>(?!.*<br>).*useless/', '', $text));
```

Above code prints:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consectetur adipisicing elit, <br>
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. .
```

Use negative lookahead lookup `(?!.*<br>)` to find last `<br>`.

Comment: Why the extra dot at the end?

Comment: @user4035, because the delimiter is `useless`, not `useless.`.

Comment: In this case his case his task contains a contradiction: he has delimiter 'useless', but no 2-nd dot in the ideal result.

Comment: This is specific to his example string. It won't work with other strings that don't end with `useless`. Why not match to the end of the string instead. `/(?s)<br>(?!.*<br>).*$/`

Comment: @TanvirChowdhury, OP does mention about that case. To handle the string that does not end with `useless`, should use `/(?s)<br>(?!.*<br>).*?(useless|$)/`.

Comment: sorry there was indeed a contradiction in the question, it was just an error. Anyway, the code worked for me so thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
$modified_text = preg_replace('/^(.*)<br>(.*)$/s', '$1', $original_text);
```

This should create a `modified_text` variable that contains everything up to the last `<br>` in `original_text`.

Comment: Without `(?s)` flag, `.` does not match newline. In addition to that, this code takes no account of the delimiter.

Comment: My example uses the `PCRE_DOTALL` modifier. In this case `.` will match newlines. I felt that the text was `<br>` delimited and my example will remove the last occurrence. Am I not understanding something about the question?

Comment: Sorry, I missed `/s`. OP mentioned `"useless"` delimiter in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$txt = preg_replace('~<br>(?>[^<u]++|<(?!br>)|u(?!seless))*(?>useless\.?|$)~', '', $txt);
```

interest:

- few backtracks
- few lookahead tests (only when a `<` or an `u` is find)
- dotall mode is useless